# How do I get the “FreeBusy” method to return complete information?

Tags: vba, outlook

I've Outlook VBA which looks up the FreeBusy status of a number of meeting rooms.

The following code:

```
sResult = olRecipient.FreeBusy(olCurrentItem.Start, 15, True)
```

returns incomplete FreeBusy information, often all zeros.

If I call it again a second later then I get a string which contains some of the correct FreeBusy information.

I wrote a small loop which requested the FreeBusy information, waited a second and then requested it again. If the string returned had changed, then it would continue looping until the information returned was unchanged.

In several cases and on completely random rooms, it would take up to 5 seconds/attempts before the FreeBusy information stopped populating! Even then, it turned out that some of the rooms were still returning incomplete information.

**My question therefore is:** How do I call the FreeBusy method on a room and know that the string returned is accurate?

Comment: What type of item does olCurrentItem represent? The only reference I find to "Start" in Outlook's VBA object model is to SyncObject.Start. Nothing else has a Start method.

Answer (score 0):

You can try http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb646996(v=office.12).aspx or http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb219898(v=office.12).aspx. I tried the following, it works fine for me. If you use Visual Studio, better debug the outcomes of the f/b info.

Comment: Thanks for the links. However both of them seem to demonstrate how to use the FreeBusy method and appear to assume that the information returned is correct first time - which is the problem I'm having.